# datetime.datetime.strptime says wrong format. how to solve?

Tags: python, datetime, format

why isn't that working?

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("13.11.2021 16:30", "%d.%m.%y %H:%M")
```

Error: "ValueError: time data '13.11.2021 16:30' does not match format '%d.%m.%y %H:%M'"

thanks!!

Comment: Use capital `%Y` to match your year with 4 digits

Answer (score 1):

You should use it like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
dl = datetime.strptime('12.11.2021 18:54', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
```

The missing point is your year parameter --> `y into Y`.

Cheers.